# How can I multiply arrays of different lengths and shapes?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays:

```py
state_change_array = np.asarray([[-1,  0,  0], [-2, 1, 0], [2, -1, 0], [0, -1, 1]])
```

and a second array called `rxn_vector = np.random.poisson(lam)`. Where `lam` is an array of length 4 and shape: `(4,)`, the actual numbers in the array vary deepening on which iteration I'm on earlier input parameters.

I want to multiply each row of state_change_array by the respective elements of rxn_vector, row_1*element_1, row_2*element_2 etc...

I originally tried this:

```py
for j in range(len(rxn_vector)): 
    state_change_lambda = np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j])*rxn_vector[j])
```

Which returns state_change_lambda as an array of length 3 and shape `(3,)`.

The problem with that is I need the array to have the length of 4 so I can use it with another array further on. My first question is if `state_change_array` and `rxn_vector` both have length 4 is `state_change_lambda` all of a sudden of length 3?

And my second question I how can I fix this? I have tried using nested for loops like below to go through each array element-wise.

```
for i in range(len(state_change_array)):
    for j in range(len(rxn_vector)): 
        state_change_lambda = np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[i, j])*rxn_vector[j])
```

But that results in

```
IndexError --> IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3
```

Both NumPy and scipy are already imported btw

Any suggestions? 
Cheers

EDIT: This is the full code below

```
while tao < tmax:
propensity = propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)        
a0 = (sum(propensity))  # a0 is a numpy.float64
if a0 == 0.0:
    break   # if reaction cannot fire corresponding element in rxn_vector should be zero --> tau leaping method 
lam = (propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)*delta_t)  
rxn_vector = np.random.poisson(lam)
# ^^^ rxn_vector length = 4    
print("rxn_vector length:\n", rxn_vector)
if tao + delta_t > tmax:
    break
tao += delta_t  # divide tao by delta_t to calculate number of leaps
leap_counter = tao / delta_t 
if popul_num.any() < 0:
    break
else:   
    if tao >= 2/a0:     
        for j in range(len(rxn_vector)): 
            state_change_lambda = np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j])*rxn_vector[j]) # shape (3,) and length = 3 
            # IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with length 3

            print("state change lambda:\n", len(state_change_lambda))
            # state change lambda --> change in the number of molecules after each reaction is fired --> len = 3 
            # state change lambda needs to be length four! This is where my problem is! 
            # rxn_vector is length 4!  
            popul_num = popul_num + state_change_lambda
        new_propensity = propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate) # shape = (4,)   
        for m in range(len(propensity)):
            for n in range(len(new_propensity)):
                # remove one of the nested for loops --> which one? 
                # both propensity and new_propensity have len = 4 
                propensity_check = propensity[m] + state_change_lambda # shape = (3,) len = 3
                print("propensity_check:\n", len(propensity_check))
                # propensity is len/shape = 4/(4,) 
                # state change lambda and therefore propensity_check are len/shape = 3/(3,)
                # the longer is fitted to the shorter for propensity check --> this is the Error
                # state_change_lambda is the problem --> shorter length --> ONLY THREE MOLECULE TYPES IN SYSTEM!
                if propensity_check[m] - new_propensity[n] >= epsi*a0:  # IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis zero with size 3
                    print("The value of delta_t {} choosen is too large".format(delta_t))
                    break                    
        popul_num_all.append(popul_num)   
    else:
        t = np.random.exponential(1/a0)
        rxn_probability = propensity / a0   
        num_rxn = np.arange(rxn_probability.size)       
        if tao + t > tmax:      
            tao = tmax
            break
        j = stats.rv_discrete(values=(num_rxn, rxn_probability)).rvs() 
        tao = tao + t
        popul_num = popul_num + np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j]))  
        print("Simulation time:\n", t, tao)
        popul_num_all.append(popul_num)
```

Comment: `state_change_array` is (4,3) shape.  `state_change_array[0]` is (3,) shape (1d array with 3 items).  You shouldn't need those `np.squeeze(np.asarray...` calls.  When you test code, test each piece, and examine the results.

Comment: In the loop you set `state_change_lambda` each time, but you don't accumulate the values anywhere.  Sounds like you skipped a chapter in the basic Python introduction.

Comment: I've edited the post and added the full code, I pass the values of state_change_lambda to a different variables, their stored and accumulated there

Comment: Removing the np.squeeze, results in a similar indexing error, IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3. On the line: if propensity_check[m] - new_propensity[n] >= epsi*a0

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that `squeeze` was causing the problem; just that it (probably) wasn't necessary.  If the array is already shape (3,) it doesn't need `squeeze` to make it 1d.